# Simultaneously downloading and playing a song that is pieced together from multiple URLs

Tags: ios, streaming, avfoundation, avplayer

I have an NSArray of strings that are URLs.  Each URL in the array points to data that is associated with a section of the song.  I can play the full song with the following code, which fully downloads the song to a single file then plays it from that file:

```
// Get file path to store song locally
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/temp.mp3", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];

// Remove current temp file and create a new one
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

// Initialize loop variables
NSMutableData *songData = nil;
NSUInteger totalLength = 0;
NSString *localURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", [filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURL *localURL = [NSURL URLWithString:localURLString];

for (NSString *stringURL in urls) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    songData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    totalLength += songData.length;
    [fileHandle writeData:songData];
    [fileHandle synchronizeFile];
}

[fileHandle closeFile];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:localURL]];
[self.player play];
```

Now I'm trying to get the entire song to play seamlessly without downloading the whole thing first (so basically streaming it, but instead of streaming from one URL I have to piece the song together from multiple while I stream).

What options do I have?

UPDATE 1:

I've tried to generate the manifest file, there is no error writing the file, and the manifestString seems to be in the correct format, but the player does not play.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *manifestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/manifest.m3u8", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];
NSMutableString *manifestString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[manifestString appendString:@"#EXTM3\n"];
for (NSString *stringURL in urls) {
    [manifestString appendFormat:@"%@\n", stringURL];
}
[manifestString appendString:@"#EXT-X-ENDLIST"];
NSError *err = nil;
[manifestString writeToFile:manifestPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
if (err) {
    NSLog(@"error writing manifest: %@", err);
}
NSString *manifestURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", [filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURL *manifestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:manifestURLString];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:manifestURL]];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: Please provide your hls manifest. Maybe you have an error there

Comment: You're missing the following tags in your manifest:
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0

Also, it should be #EXTM3U not #EXTM3. I don't know if the #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION tag is required. The value of this tag is supposed to be the length of the longest segment in your manifest (rounded up).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're targeting iOS, have you considered using HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html

Although it's typically used for video + audio, you can create an audio-only manifest file on your server that lists each of the segments of the song sequentially and AVPlayer will take care of downloading it piece by piece automatically for you.

For example, I took a song (in a file called sample.mp3) and segmented it for use in HLS with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp3 -acodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_list index.m3u8 segment%05d.mp3
```

This takes the input file (sample.mp3) and splits it into 5 second segments. It spits out a manifest file (index.m3u8 in this case):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXTINF:5.015511,
segment00000.mp3
#EXTINF:4.989389,
segment00001.mp3
#EXTINF:5.015511,
segment00002.mp3
#EXTINF:4.989389,
segment00003.mp3
#EXTINF:5.015511,
segment00004.mp3
#EXTINF:4.989378,
segment00005.mp3
#EXTINF:4.989389,
segment00006.mp3
#EXTINF:5.015511,
segment00007.mp3
#EXTINF:4.989389,
segment00008.mp3
#EXTINF:5.015511,
segment00009.mp3
#EXTINF:4.989389,
segment00010.mp3
#EXTINF:4.571433,
segment00011.mp3
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

If you pass a URL to the manifest to AVPlayer, it can do the rest.

Comment: Is this possible if I only have access to the URLs?  ie. can I create the manifest file on the iOS side and pass it to the AVPlayer?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter where the manifest comes from. The segments can be identified by their absolute URLs (e.g. http://blahblah.com/segment00000.mp3 instead of just segment00000.mp3). And I had though that the duration (the #EXTINF) stuff was required, but I just tried to delete that and it still works. Looks like AVPlayer is VERY forgiving.

Comment: Okay, I tried generating the manifest and playing it that way but the player doesn't seem to be playing.  I updated the question with the code I tried.

Comment: When I download m3u8 url., I am geeting a '.movpkg' path how can I get the .ts file from the same