# Streaming Technique from pocketcast in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, video, video-streaming, buffer

I've been asked by my client whether it is possible to download a video and stream it once a bit has downloaded, just like pocketcasts does. His reasoning is this will allow him to store his video files on a site such as godaddy and bypass the need to stream the file to the phone which normally requires a dedicated server.

Is this even possible? if so do you know anywhere I can look to find out how pocketcasts does it? At the moment my app just streams an mp4.

Thanks for looking,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're targetting iOS, HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) is your friend: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Please see my answer here for how you can use it: [Simultaneously downloading and playing a song that is pieced together from multiple URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102882/simultaneously-downloading-and-playing-a-song-that-is-pieced-together-from-multi/19103137#19103137)

It's very easy to run a long movie through the mediafilesegmenter tool from Apple (or FFMPEG) which spits out a number of small .ts files (MPEG 2 Transport Stream). Then you create a manifest (a .m3u8 file) which describes how these files fit together (which mediafilesegment will create for you too!). Then you just put the manifest file and the .ts files on a hosting provider (like GoDaddy) and you're all set.

For example, given a file called test.mp4, first turn it into a .ts file with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb test.ts
```

Then turn it into a series of HLS segments with mediafilesegmenter (the same can be done using the ffmpeg segment muxer, but mediafilesegmenter seems to be more robust):

```
mediafilesegmenter -t 3 test.ts
```

The result is a bunch of 3 second clips (that's what `-t 3` means) and an manifest file called `prog_index.m3u8`. The contents of that look like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:2.99520,    
fileSequence0.ts
#EXTINF:2.99520,    
fileSequence1.ts
#EXTINF:2.99520,    
fileSequence2.ts
#EXTINF:2.99520,    
fileSequence3.ts
...
#EXTINF:0.37440,    
fileSequence75.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Simply putting all of the .ts files and the .m3u8 file on a web server and pointing your AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController in iOS at the URL for the .m3u8 will get you an excellent streaming performance.

Comment: I'll give that a go soon, thanks for such a detailed reply :)

Comment: Hi Ksimons,

After speaking to a member of GoDaddy they've said the HTTP live streaming still uses a streaming service so it can therefore not be used on one of there "unlimited bandwidth" packages. Thanks for your help though, I'll remember it for future projects :)